# let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$. Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I know I will need to use the definition of uniform continuity but I don't know how to go about proving $f$ is integrable

Comment: A function $f$ is integrable if …?

Comment: I am sorry but this is not a good question. First of all, you are asking for a proof that you can find in any textbook with many details. Secondly, it seems you are not making any effort to understand the standard proof of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the following result.

> Let $a,b\in\mathbb R,a<b$ and $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb R$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is Riemann-integrable
> 2. For $\varepsilon>0$ there exist step functions $\varphi,\psi$ with $\varphi\leq f\leq \psi$ and $$\int\limits_{a}^{b}\! \psi(x)-\varphi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\leq \varepsilon.$$

Outline of the proof for: $f[a,b]\rightarrow$ is continuous, then $f$ is integrable.

As $[a,b]$ is a compact intervall, there exists $\delta>0$ so that for all $x,y\in[a,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$: $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)}.$$

Choose $n\in\mathbb N$ with $\dfrac{b-a}{n}<\delta$. Define a partiton $(x_i)_{0\leq i\leq n}$ of the intervall $[a,b]$ via $$x_i:=a+i\cdot\frac{b-a}{n},\quad 0\leq i\leq n.$$
Now let $$\varphi(x):=f(x_i)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)},\psi(x):=f(x_i)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2(b-a)},~\quad x_{i-1}\leq x<x_i,1\leq i\leq n.$$

Now we just have to put everything together (which is left as an excrcise to you).

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: yes I would. I am downvoting this post although it's of good quality (and would have upvoted it in a different circumstance). The problem is that the question shows no research or work effort from the OP, and it is very classic in the sense that a proof could be found in many sites just through a Google search. Answering these sorts of questions encourages users to keep asking as such, and this lowers the quality of posts on this site. Thus, answers to such questions should be discouraged in my opinion.

Comment: @BolzWeir I'd generally agree with you, that one should show his own work. Still (and of course I'm biased as I decided to post this answer) I think that I didn't give too much information on the proof and left some/enough work for the OP. Instead of giving a full detailed answer I often try to just give hints, but often those answers that give the complete answer (even if it is just a simple calculation e.g. completing the square) are the ones that are wanted. I guess for my answer here we could argue all day long if it is too much, if it is barely enough...

Comment: @BolzWeir (continued...) but this wouldn't lead anywhere. Thank you for your comment, it's always nice to know why one doesn't like your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, we do need to use the definition of uniform continuity. Given $\epsilon > 0 \; \exists\delta>0, \; \text{with } \delta<b-a, \; \text{such that given }x,y\in[a,b],$ $$|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$$

Now let $\{x_0,x_1,...x_n\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that the maximum distance between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ is $\delta$. Now continuous functions on closed intervals obtain its supremum and infimum on the interval, so there exist $u_k,v_k\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ such that $$f(u_k) = \text{sup}\{f(x):x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]\}$$ $$f(v_k) = \text{inf}\{f(x):x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}]\}$$
By our assumption that $x_{k+1} - x_k<\delta$, we have $|u_k-v_k|<\delta$.
So by our definition of uniform continuity, we have that $$f(u_k)-f(v_k)<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$$
Then we have that the difference between the upper sum and the lower sum is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(u_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(v_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k) \\=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [f(u_k)-f(v_k](x_{k+1}-x_k)\\<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (x_{k+1}-x_k)\\=\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}(x_n-x_0) = \epsilon$$